# 90th percentile using date diff

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been using the following

```
DATEDIFF(dd,OrderReceivedDate, DeliveryDate) DaysToDelivery
```

to work out the  number of days taken between the `OrderReceivedDate` and `DeliveryDate`

I wish to work out the 90th percentile , per department.

I have the following

```
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,OrderReceivedDate, DeliveryDate))   
OVER (PARTITION BY Department) as 90thpercentile
```

I cannot get this to work

when trying to use a `PERCENTILE_DISC` is date diff not allowed? Or does it have to use a stored figure?

I keep getting the error -  OrderReceivedDate or DeliveryDate not in the aggregate or group by clause

please help

Comment: hi can you give a create script of some temp data and a table. And I can help you get this to work.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Giving incorrect results or an error?

Comment: adding your sample code below. now what is your expected value???? or resultset your trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datediff` support PERCENTILE_DISC and i have tested your query in 2016 sql server it works fine

```
 SELECT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,OrderReceivedDate, DeliveryDate))
                            OVER (PARTITION BY Department) as "90thpercentile"
from t
```

I think problem in column alias name , use  double quote or [] for
number start in column name

Comment: I keep getting OrderReceivedDate, DeliveryDate not in the aggregate or group by clause

Comment: I added the group by the following OrderReceivedDate, DeliveryDate and the [] worked too thanks team x

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code ..what is your expected result-set???

```
--drop table #Temp_Orders
create table #Temp_Orders

(
OrderNo int null
,Department varchar(30) null
,OrderReceivedDate date null
,DeliveryDate date null
)

insert into #Temp_Orders values
(1,'Acc','12-1-2018','12-2-2018')
,(1,'Acc','12-5-2018','12-8-2018')
,(1,'Warehouse','12-1-2018','12-12-2018')
,(1,'Warehouse','12-10-2018','12-12-2018')
,(1,'Acc','11-1-2018','11-29-2018')
,(1,'Acc','10-1-2018','10-9-2018')


select *
,PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,OrderReceivedDate, DeliveryDate))
OVER (PARTITION BY Department) as [90thpercentile]
from #Temp_Orders
```

Comment: well here is a fun fact if you add one more row ; like so
(2,'Acc','09-1-2018','12-2-2018')
Your 90thpercentile value goes up for [Acc] dept from 28 to 92. Is this what your looking for. Anways you have 2 proposed answers. I hope it works out for what your looking for.